# Creating mixed width and height cells in a Dash layout

Tags: css, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I've seen multiple posts about how to create mixed height/width using `Dash`'s built in `dbc` components and didn't see a truly flexible, easy to use method for making the following:

[image: layout]

here are some links,

[Plotly-Dash: How to span a component across two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004138/plotly-dash-how-to-span-a-component-across-two-rows)

[dash bootsrap card over multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70512792/dash-bootsrap-card-over-multiple-rows)

https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/issues/286

The question: how do I do this in a flexible and clean way?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a modified html `table`

```py
from dash import html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


def table_cell(content, col_span, row_span=1):
    if type(content) == str:
        content = dbc.Alert(content, style={'height': '100%', 'margin': '0px', 'border-width': '5px', 'border-color': 'black'}),
    return html.Td(
        content,
        colSpan=col_span,
        rowSpan=row_span,
        style={'margin': '0px', 'padding': '0px'},
    )


def generate_layout():

    return html.Div([
        html.Table([
            html.Colgroup([
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
                html.Col(style={'width': '8.33%'}),
            ]),
            html.Tr([table_cell('data_trace', 6),
                     table_cell('data_trace_zoom', 3),
                     table_cell('info_box', 3, 2)]),
            html.Tr([table_cell('event_trace', 6), table_cell('event_trace_zoom', 3)]),
            html.Tr([table_cell('counts_per_s', 6),
                     table_cell('counts_hist', 3),
                     table_cell('heatmap', 3, 2)]),
            html.Tr([table_cell('flow_rate_per_s', 6),
                     table_cell('flow_rate_hist', 3)]),
            html.Tr([table_cell('conc_per_s', 6), table_cell('peak_profiles', 6)]),
        ], style={'display': 'table', 'width': '100%', 'border-collapse': 'collapse', 'height': '100%'})
    ], style={'height': '100vh'})
```